# How to get the console output of a live web session in firefox without keeping the tab open?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, console, developer-tools

I'm working on a project that involves testing some user inactivity functions on a web page. I want to see the console output of the page in a tab in firefox, but I don't want to keep the tab open, because I want to test what happens when the user switches to another tab or app. I want to log the console output to my terminal, so I can monitor it remotely.
I've tried using some tools like Selenium, VS Code, and Chrome remote debugging protocol, but they are either too complicated to set up, or they don't work for every site. I've also tried using some web technologies like WebSockets, WebExtensions, and WebRTC, but they require a lot of code and access to external services.
Is there an easy and reliable way to do this with firefox? Or is there a better way to test my user inactivity functions, without relying on the console output?
Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.